# Error with HTML5 Video Background in a SharePoint Page Layout

Tags: html, sharepoint, video, page-layout

I am trying to get a blurred video background on the homepage for my SharePoint site similar to sites like airbnb and bing. I have removed the doctype as xhtml and replaced as html, and entered a video tag with video residing in the _layouts file on the sharepoint server.

The video renders correctly in the background when I view the page layout by itself in a browser. But when I view a page with this page layout within sharepoint I get a 'Sorry, something went wrong' error. It normally works fine without the video and amendment to standard XHTML !DOCTYPE

Evidently there isn't something fundamentally wrong with my html since it renders in the browser. Are there any sharepoint html5 wizards out there who can help?

```
<div class="main" style="background-image:url('')">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1; left:0px; right:0px;">
    <source src="videos/pencils.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint?  SharePoint 2010 doesn't support HTML 5 in IE because SharePoint forces IE to render as IE8.

Comment: Sharepoint 2013. I'm wondering whether it's something to do with MIME types, if I am rendering an MP4 maybe sharepoint doesn't have this defined out of the box

Comment: The video is now working. Turns out I needed to self-close the source tag.

Comment: Now having trouble with z-index. I think there must be something on sharepoint that is transluscent white which means when z-index of the video is -1 it is very washed out. have ensured opacity:1.